# Bullet point after every comma Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, textarea

I am using Rails 4. I have a text area where users enter different ingredients for their food. I would like to automatically have the ingredients bullet pointed using `<li>` when separating the different ingredients with a comma, so they are bulleted on the show page.

I am having trouble finding documentation on doing so. Can someone point me in that direction or let me know the best way to do this?

I am currently using a text_area for users to input ingredients:

```
<%= f.text_area :ingredients, :rows => "8", :cols => "80", :placeholder => "Ingredient 1, ingredient 2, ingredient 3..." %>
```

Here is my view:

```
<h1>Ingredients:</h1><br>
<%= subarticle.ingredients.html_safe %>
```

is currently just displays as paragraph form.

Comment: May be you should have a look at [**tinymce-rails**](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails).

Comment: Hi Kathan, do you mean the user will type the name of one ingredient, then a comma, then the name of another ingredient and so on, and you want that to be displayed as a list of items that is updated as the user types?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I would only like it to be displayed as a list on the show page. So after the user submits the form, the ingredients get bullet pointed. @cmoran92

Comment: Please post your show page code.

Comment: What happens when you wrap `<%= subarticle.ingredients.html_safe %>` inside a `<ul>` like this `<ul><%= subarticle.ingredients.html_safe %></ul>`?

Comment: How do you store the ingredients in your DB? Would it work for you to split the string with the ingredients into an array and store it serialized with YAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it helps you or not, it is a brute force system I've applied.

```
<% txt = "A,B,C" %>

<% out = "<ul>" %>
<% txt.split(',').each {|s| out += ("<li>" + s.to_s + "</li>")} %>
<% out += "</ul>" %>
<%= out.html_safe %>
```

**OutPut:**

- A
- B
- C

Answer (score 3):

A better approach would be [storing ingredients in database as Array](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize)

In the view, it will as simple as this,

```
<ul>
  <% food.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
    <li><%= ingredient %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```